# Which is more expensive? Keeping threads running in Thread Pool or Creating new Thread?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

Creating new thread is considered as expensive task. But in thread Pull we create many threads and keep them running even no task is available to perform. why it is not more expensive to keep idle threads running rather than creating threads as and when needed? Though Threads are idle they must be occupying the resources like fixed memory, OS schedule etc. Then how thread pool is more optimized way?

Answer (score 1):

Because creating and destroying threads is expensive. If your threads are idle, then you don't have a lot of work to do. You don't need to work efficiently when you don't have a lot of work to do, you need to work efficiently when you *do* have a lot of work to do.

Comment: but resource allocation happens at the time when we call the start() method. For idle threads also, start() method already called. Then where can be expense saving?

Comment: The expense saving comes from not having to create and destroy threads and instead re-using them. There are other benefits of a thread pool as well, but that's usually the biggest one.